# Which feature scaling method to use before PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a Kaggle dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-customer-satisfaction. I understand some sort of feature scaling is needed before PCA. I read from [this post](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html#z-score-standardization-or-min-max-scaling) and [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69157/why-do-we-need-to-normalize-data-before-analysis) that normalization is best, however it was standardizing that gave me the highest performance (AUC-ROC).

I tried all the feature scaling methods from sklearn, including: RobustScaler(), Normalizer(), MinMaxScaler(), MaxAbsScaler() and StandardScaler(). Then using the scaled data, I did PCA. But it turns out that the optimal numbers of PCA's obtained vary greatly between these methods.

Here's the code I use:

```
# Standardize the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

# Find the optimal number of PCA 
pca = PCA(n_components=X_train_scaled.shape[1])
pca.fit(X_train_scaled)
ratios = pca.explained_variance_ratio_

# Plot the explained variance ratios
x = np.arange(X_train_scaled.shape[1])
plt.plot(x, np.cumsum(ratios), '-o')
plt.xlabel("Number of PCA's")
plt.ylabel("Cumulated Sum of Explained Variance")
plt.title("Variance Explained by PCA's")

# Find the optimal number of PCA's
for i in range(np.cumsum(ratios).shape[0]):
  if np.cumsum(ratios)[i] >= 0.99:
    num_pca = i + 1
    print "The optimal number of PCA's is: {}".format(num_pca)
    break
  else:
    continue
```

These are the different number of PCA's I got using different scalers.

- RobustScaler: 9
- Normalizer: 26
- MinMaxScaler: 45
- MaxAbsScaler: 45
- StandardScaler: 142

So, my question is, which method is the right one for feature scaling in this situation? Thanks!

Comment: This is just a comment - 142 principal components sort of defeats the purpose of dimension reduction, which is one of the core use cases of principal component analysis. I'm also unsure explaining >99% variance through PCA is optimal,or something that people usually attempt to do. May be worth revisiting your process/asking around to make sure it's statistically sound.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Data on which the PCA-transformation is calculated should be normalized, meaning in this case:

- zero mean
- unit variance

This basically is sklearns `StandardScaler`, which i would prefer of your candidates. The reasons are explained on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) and also [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_necessary_to_normalize_data_before_performing_principle_component_analysis).

- sklearns Normalizer is missing zero-mean
- Both Min-Max scalers are missing unit-variance
- Robust scaler could work on some data (outliers!), but i would prefer StandardScaler.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @sascha!

Answer (score 3):

You need to normalize the features or their variances will not be comparable. Think of a feature where the variance is a ratio to the range. A larger range produces a larger variance. You don't want the PCA to focus on variables with larger ranges.

R code illustrating change in var due to range

```
> v=runif(100)
> x=v/4 # change only the range
> var(x)
[1] 0.004894443
> var(v)
[1] 0.07831109
> var(x/sum(x))
[1] 3.169311e-05
> var(v/sum(v))
[1] 3.169311e-05
```

After normalizing, we see the same variance with x and v.